# Navigation properties and avoiding circular references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have recently refactored my domain model to remove circular references that were caused by navigation properties.  Here is the basic structure of the domain model:

- User has many Games
- Game has many UserTeams
- User has many UserTeams

Previously I had a navigation property in the UserTeam model, User.

To avoid circular references (I was getting issues when Unit Testing with autofixture), I removed the User navigation property from UserTeam.

Previously, in my View, when looping through Games, I could get the User for a UserTeam like so:

```
foreach (game in games)
{
    foreach (userteam in game)
    {
        userteam.User.UserName
    }
}
```

Now I cannot do that (as User is no longer a property of UserTeam).

So, now I have to call a method from the View, something like like `GetUser(userteam.UserId)`.

This seems very inefficient (having to do dataaccess on every loop iteration) compared to the previous structure.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe view models can help you?

Comment: How? It seems like I'll need a new model (viewmodel) to mimic what the old one did (with the circular reference), and a new set of repository methods... so I'm just sidestepping the circular reference issue....

Comment: Well, the better way is to have the circular reference back to `User`. It isn't necessarily anything bad to have in your model. Can't you ignore that property in autofixture? I mean, if you want to know the username of the UserTeam you need the user reference, simple as that. With a view model you could flatten that a bit, and maybe add the username directly to the UserTeam.

Comment: @Jle how exactly could you flatten it in the viewmodel and add the username to the userteam?  Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

> To avoid circular references (I was getting issues when Unit Testing with autofixture), I removed the User navigation property from UserTeam.
>
> Is there a better way?

1. If you left `User` property for the `Game` class, you can use `Game.User` instead of `UserTeam.User` to access `User`.
2. If you are to remove just every circular reference there are options.

Every bidirectional association (for example, `User <-> Game`) makes circular dependency.

To remove circular dependency associations have to be made unidirectional (for example, `User <- Game` or `User -> Game`) with the option which association end to remove.

So, instead of removing `User` property from the `Game` class it may be more appropriate to remove `Games` property from the `User` class and to add a service method `GetGames(User)` which queries all games in a single call.